# Htaccess nice url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have again problem with my htaccess redirection.

I have this in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^strana/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?pn=$1 [NC,L]
```

When i put in my browser http://www.stovelkybiel.eu/strana/2 it works. But if i click on page its redirect me to http://www.stovelkybiel.eu/index?pn=2

I have this php script:

```
$paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';

            for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++) {
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
                if($i >= $pagenum+4) {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

When i replace '?pn=' with 'strana/' its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this PHP script:

```
$paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';

        for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++) {
            $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="/strana/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            if($i >= $pagenum+4) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated, but I would move the second condition to the for loop condition, e.g. instead of

```
for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++) {
    $paginationCtrls .= ...;
    if($i >= $pagenum+4) {
        break;
    }
}
```

join the two

```
for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last && $i <= $pagenum+4; $i++) {
    $paginationCtrls .= ...;
}
```

---

[@Croises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42045452/1741542) already showed how to fix the pagination controls.